# Cursor is blinking in UITextField but keyboard doesn't appear

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I got a simple detail view with a textfield.
In detail's viewController I wrote this code:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"is textField 1st responder %d", [self.textField isFirstResponder]);
}
```

When I push the detail into a navigation controller, I see "*is textField 1st responder 0*" in my log.
The keyboard doesn't appear.
But the textfield has blinking cursor.

What happens in this moment? Why the keyboard doesn't appears? I did try to catch a notification "KeyboardDidShown" in my AppDelegate but didn't catch anything:
[image]

Here is my master view design :

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `self.textField` isn't `nil` and is already on your view when you call `becomeFirstResponder`?

Comment: I've just tried to move this code to viewDidLoad method - nothing changes.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. :) Where do you initialize your `UITextField` and where do you add it to your `UIView`?

Comment: Where are you setting the UITextFieldDelegate?

Comment: Andreas, I initialize the textField in IB.

Comment: DenVog, I don't use textField delegation. Keyboard should appears without the delegation. Am I wrong?

Comment: You picked the bellow answer as "The Correct Answer" but it is so vague. I have the same problem but can't figure out how to solve it. The codes in rghost are deleted. This community is for helping all people not only yourself. Please make the answer more clear.

Comment: @AliBZ i've edited the answer, but it may be invisible atm. so here you go - two projects: solved http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34188625/hh2_Solved.zip

and the original one with bugs http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34188625/hh2.zip . You can check that the keyboard doesn't appears at detail view (you create some row on master view before)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does calling `reloadInputViews` help?

Comment: "If the current object is not the first responder, this method has no effect." the problem is - I can't find where is my first responder. I've checked all views with this method 

`- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{    
    NSLog(@"is view 1st responder %d", [self isFirstResponder]);
}`

Comment: I've tried to send  `reloadInputViews` to my textField in viewDidAppear but nothing happens

Comment: Can you send the project? May be a sample one showing the issue.

Comment: That is solved now... :)
The reason for the issue was that you had two different UIWindow objects.
One - in your app delegate
Two - in your view controller xib. Here instead of uiwindow it should had been UIView. and in its viewDidLoad add TabBarview.

You can download the solved project at : http://rghost.net/42397367