# Keyboard doesn't come up with multiple UIWindows

Tags: ios, keyboard, uiwindow

I have created a loading UIWindow which I call and `makeKeyAndVisible` when I start loading. After I'm finished, I `makeKeyAndVisible` my main UIWindow. But my problem is after doing this, when I click on a text field, the keyboard doesn't come up. This is asked in [Cursor is blinking in UITextField but keyboard doesn't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960410/cursor-is-blinking-in-uitextfield-but-keyboard-doesnt-appear) but I can't find the right answer.

EDIT: in UIView, when I click on the addressbar, keyboard does come up but I can't type. But in google's page, when I click on search text field, keyboard doesn't come up.

```
- (void)showLoading:(NSString*)text
{
loadingWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
mainWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;    

[loadingWindow setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, boundWidth, boundHeight)];
[loadingWindow setRootViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init]];
[loadingWindow.rootViewController setView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
[loadingWindow.rootViewController.view setFrame:loadingWindow.frame];

[loadingWindow setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)hideLoading
{
[loadingWindow setHidden:YES];
[loadingWindow removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. When I wanted to put the loadingWindow on top, I was calling `[loadingWindow makeKeyAndVisible]` which I believe leads to the problem. Now I only use `[loadingWindow setHidden:NO]`.

Comment: Why are you adding a new window?  iOS applications should only have one window, and it should only be set in the AppDelegate.

Comment: I believe you are wrong. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232398/advantages-problems-examples-of-adding-another-uiwindow-to-an-ios-app

Comment: "Unless an app can display content on an external device screen, an app has only one window." [UIWindow documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html).